# What is the best way to automate PDF page extraction and conversion into jpg for downloaded files in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, automation, file-conversion

From time to time I need to check a webpage, download a PDF file from there, find something inside, extract that page and convert it to an image. I can do it easily on macOS, but on iOS it gets more complicated. It would be great if I could on the way, using my iPhone.

I have been trying a way to do it using the apps I know. My last try was with Workflow, but it seems that it does not support PDF to JPG conversion. I may try to write some code in Pythonista and it can probably work out, but i would prefer a simpler solution. Is there an app/solution that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this.

PDF to Images by Miles Jordan Software
https://appsto.re/us/eGbaY.i

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review